# prevent <body> content to be displayed on browser in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, perl, cgi

I am new to Perl and HTML and trying to build a GUI using Perl + CGI + HTML . In the  part of the HTML i am trying to login to server abc using send expect commands in Perl. In the console if i give "telnet abc " i will see various messages as connecting to clients , checking stats etc . Since i am implementing in this in Browser i "don't want" the browser to show the above messages which i get in the console. Please help me on how to achieve this .

```
      <HTML> 
      <HEAD>
      </HEAD>
       <body>

          send ("telnet abc"); # i dont want these things to be displayed in the browser.
         expect("messages");
      </body>
       </HTML>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is this your actual code?

Comment: You are using it in wrong way. You have to write a perl with cgi script or program which generates the html. You cant put the send and expect in body. Please see some perl cgi tutorials for this. Go step by step in the learning it.

Comment: All html sent to the browser can be 'seen' one way or another, as it is basically downloaded to the viewing pc. You may make the displayed elements invisible with css say, but the source is still there.

Comment: can u please give me an example @doncoyote

Comment: right click view source on a browser display will most times give you the html source, including whether an element has a class which makes it invisible. The browsers' function is to convert the source into human readable format.

Comment: possible duplicate of [interface between perl script and HTML with CGI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22245873/interface-between-perl-script-and-html-with-cgi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use log_user(0); before the expect statement .. If you are declaring an expect object as $exp then

```
$exp->log_user(0);
```

will prevent the messages of send expect statement to be displayed on browser.

Answer (score 1):

Perl runs serverside, your client side is HTML/CSS/JavaScript. Interact with perl functions on the server side by using [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). A JavaScript framework like [jQuery can do much of the hard work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29#jQuery_example) for you.

You would create your UI in HTML/CSS. Test this and ensure it works and displays as expected. Then beging adding in AJAX calls to your server side functions, updating the UI as required.

Comment: can i include the send expect statements in <script> tag because i want them to execute by not display . and AJAX is it easier for a beginner ?

Comment: @user3095218 no, it doesn't work like this. This is HTML, your calls to Perl code won't work inline from HTML. See my answer. Perl runs serverside, HTML is displayed in the browser.

Comment: can u just give me a small example please ???  @Dr.Avalanche

Comment: @user3095218 the link in my answer has an example