# interface between perl script and HTML with CGI

Tags: javascript, html, perl, cgi

I am new to Perl and HTML . I have written a back end script in Perl using send expect statements, for loops and subroutines. In the Perl script i am logging in to the server and sending some commands and expecting server prompt and finally exit .Now i am trying to bring it to front end using HTML. I am using CGI as a framework to achieve this. This is my part of the code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Expect;
use Switch;
use warnings;
use 5.008;
use Data::Dumper;
use CGI;

my $q = CGI->new;

my %data;
$data = $q->param('server');
print $q->header;


if($data eq 'null')
{
    print '<p> please select a server</p>';
    exit;

}


### 


    $exp->spawn($command, @parameters)
        or die "Cannot spawn $command: $!\n";

      $exp->send("string\n");


      $exp->expect($timeout, @match_patterns);


      $exp->expect($timeout,
               [ qr/regex1/ => sub { my $exp = shift;
                         $exp->send("response\n");
                         exp_continue; } ],
               [ "regexp2" , \&callback, @cbparms ],
              );


      $exp->soft_close();
```

these are the examples of send expect commands iam using to logging in to server and sending commands. but i am seeing them in the browser how they ll login . but i dont want these to be seen on browser but they should still execute in background

####

```
print "<html><head><title>Hello World</title></head>\n";
print "<body>\n";
print '<script>checked = false;function checkedAll () {if (checked == false){checked = true}else{checked = false}for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementById("sel").elements.length; i++) {document.getElementById("sel").elements[i].checked = checked;}}</script>';
print '<form action="robostats.pl " method="POST" id="sel">';
print '<input type="checkbox" onClick="checkedAll()">Select All<br />';

foreach my $i (@entire_success) {
    print '<input type="checkbox" name="sel" value="';
    print $i;
    print '">';
    print $i;
    print '<br />';
}

print '<input type="submit" value="submit">';
print '</form>';
print "</body></html>\n";
```

so when i am trying to run in the browser those send expect commands, server login prompts are all coming on the browser . I dont want them to be on the browser(they should only come in the console), I only want to capture its output in an array and display the checkboxes of the form on the browser. Please help me o how to achieve this.
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `log_user 0` in the expect script? It turns off logging of commands and results.

Comment: By the way, your script is kind of littered with print statements, you might consider using "here" documents to improve clarity and performance, e.g. print<<EOF<html><head>..... EOF

Comment: no i havent tried . I dont know how to use it . Should i include before use Expect statements??? @MarkSetchell

Comment: @MarkSetchell i just used it but it is giving internal server error , if i remove log_user 0 . i am seeing all my login details and prompts where the commands go. Pls help me

Comment: It should be the first Expect command.

Comment: @MarkSetchell i have given example of the type of send expect code i am using a i included log_user 0 . its still giving error saying Number found where operator expected at robust.pl line 14, near "log_user 0"
 (Do you need to predeclare log_user?)
syntax error at robust.pl line 14, near "log_user 0"
"use" not allowed in expression at robust.pl line 15, at end of line
BEGIN not safe after errors--compilation aborted at robust.pl line 16. .... but if i remove loguser i am getting output in console .

Comment: Oh, I see! You need... $exp->log_user(0);

Comment: hey thank u so much its working . now its not displaying on browser . in the script if i have $exp and $exp1 and $exp2 etc then i have to include $exp->log_user(0); $exp1->log_user(0); $exp2->log_user(0); before the first expect right ????????

Comment: I am not altogether sure what you are doing exactly, but just try it and see. I will submit my comments as an answer, so maybe you can accept that so thers can see resolution without wading through comments - and I get a lovely big green tick :-)

Comment: i mean i am spawning one process with $exp another with $exp1 and so on . so then i have to include $exp->log_user(0); $exp1->log_user(0); $exp2->log_user(0); before the first expect right ????????

Comment: and @MarkSetchell where will all these logs go ?????

Comment: They won't go anywhere since they will not exist. The purpose of the flag is to stop any logs being created at all. http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.15/Expect.pod

Comment: @MarkSetchell thank u and i have u a ovely big green tick :-) have a look :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to turn off logging/echoing of commands at the start of your Expect script, like this:

```
$exp->log_user(0);
```

Comment: I want to log what is happening and store it in a file . Is this possible here ?

Comment: Try this `$exp->log_file("$host.log");`

Comment: where will it be saved?

Comment: I think it comes out in "real time" - you may have to try changing the other line to `$exp->log_user(1)` to re-enable messages since it turned them off for you before.

Comment: I want $exp->log_user(0) to diable messages , but still want a log to be created :(